# Floodfill memory leak iPhone

Tags: objective-c, c, core-graphics, flood-fill

I'm implementing a `floodfill` function in C for the iPhone.

The fill works, although I'm having 2 issues.

1. The phone gives a memory warning after a few executions of the code below. Most likely a memory leak. Also note that the **unsigned char *data** *(the image data) is being free()'d at the end of the floodfill.*
2. (lesser issue) If I attempt to write **RGB** colors to pixels that are greater than approximately **(r:200,g:200,b:200,a:200)** I get weird artifacting happening. A workaround for this was to simply limit the values.

I suspect there may be a correlation between both of these problems.

The code below describes my flood-fill algorithm, using a stack:

**.h:**

```
typedef struct {
    int red;
    int green;
    int blue;
    int alpha;
} GUIColor;


struct pixel_st {
    int x;
    int y;
    struct pixel_st *nextPixel;
};
typedef struct pixel_st pixel;
```

**.m:**

```
   void floodFill(CGPoint location, GUIColor tc, GUIColor rc, size_t width, size_t height, unsigned char *data){
    if (isGUIColorEqual(tc, rc)) return;

    pixel* aPixel = (pixel *) malloc(sizeof (struct pixel_st));
    NSLog(@"sizeof aPixel : %i",(int)sizeof(aPixel));

    (*aPixel).x = location.x;
    (*aPixel).y = location.y;
    (*aPixel).nextPixel = NULL;

    int i = 0;

    NSLog(@"Replacement color A%i, R%i, G%i, B%i",rc.alpha,rc.red,rc.green, rc.blue);

    while (aPixel != NULL){
        pixel *oldPixel_p = aPixel;
        pixel currentPixel = *aPixel;
        aPixel = currentPixel.nextPixel;


        //Now we do some boundary checks
        if (!isOutOfBounds(currentPixel.x, currentPixel.y, width, height)){
            //Grab the current Pixel color
            GUIColor currentColor = getGUIColorFromPixelAtLocation(CGPointMake(currentPixel.x, currentPixel.y), width, height, data);

            if (isGUIColorSimilar(currentColor, tc)){
                //Colors are similar, lets continue the spread
                setGUIColorToPixelAtLocation(CGPointMake(currentPixel.x, currentPixel.y), rc, width,height, data);

                pixel *newPixel;


                if ((newPixel = (pixel*) malloc(sizeof(struct pixel_st))) != NULL) {
                    (*newPixel).x = currentPixel.x;
                    (*newPixel).y = currentPixel.y-1;
                    (*newPixel).nextPixel = aPixel;
                    aPixel = newPixel;

                }
                if ((newPixel = (pixel*) malloc(sizeof(struct pixel_st))) != NULL) {
                    (*newPixel).x = currentPixel.x;
                    (*newPixel).y = currentPixel.y+1;
                    (*newPixel).nextPixel = aPixel;
                    aPixel = newPixel;
                }
                if ((newPixel = (pixel*) malloc(sizeof(struct pixel_st))) != NULL) {
                    (*newPixel).x = currentPixel.x+1;
                    (*newPixel).y = currentPixel.y;
                    (*newPixel).nextPixel = aPixel;
                    aPixel = newPixel;
                }
                if ((newPixel = (pixel*) malloc(sizeof(struct pixel_st))) != NULL) {
                    (*newPixel).x = currentPixel.x-1;
                    (*newPixel).y = currentPixel.y;
                    (*newPixel).nextPixel = aPixel;
                    aPixel = newPixel;
                }
                free(oldPixel_p);
                i ++;
                if (i == width * height * 4 * 5) break;

            }


        }
    }

    free(aPixel);
}
```

This implementation of the stack is based on the `ObjFloodFill` found here:

https://github.com/OgreSwamp/ObjFloodFill/blob/master/src/FloodFill.m

Comment: Why ar u allocating memory once and then freeing multiple times inside while loop

Comment: The stack is based on the ObjFloodFill, I'm porting it over to my code, but I havent had much experience with straight-C memory management so I'm unsure.

Comment: On top of the page it is noted as "OgreSwamp2 years ago
added comment to the ScanlineFloodfill that it doesnt work "

Comment: The ScanlineFloodfill algorithm doesnt work, but the 4-way does, I'm unsure if the memory-management in it is good though

Answer (score 1):

First of all, each `if ((newPixel = (pixel*) malloc(...` inside the loop allocates new memory block, so, you have **4** allocations inside the loop and only **1** deallocation.

Second, I can't understand why don't you simply use objects on stack? Do you really need to allocate *newPixel*, *oldPixel* and so on on the **heap**? Review the implementation, there might be much simpler way to implement the same also without managing the memory issues at all.

Comment: There probably is, but i'm unsure how to go about it, I was previously using a recursive function floodfill, but that would crash the device (on the iOS simulator it would work) because of stack-overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the deallocation of `oldPixel_p`  to outside the `if` blocks, because it is "consumed" always.

Also, the final `free` only frees the first element in the list. The list may have more than one element. You need to step through the list and free all remaining elements.